# Mongodb group by on internal element

Tags: mongodb

I have data in following format

```
{
  _id:ObjectId("someid"),
  "masterKey":{
    "key1":"val1",
    "key2":"val2",
    "key3":"val3",
    "key4":"val1",
    "key5":"val2",
    "key6":"val3",
  }
}
```

And I am expecting result which group the duplicate values of master key.

The result should be similar to this. Or in any other format which finds duplicate values of keys with key name.

```
{
  _id:Object("someid"),
  "masterKey":{
    "val1":["key1","key4"],
    "val2":["key2","key5"],
    "val3":["key3","key6"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this "per document" or "accross the collection"? The latter I really don't see the point of and it's potentially "huge", the former per document is really best done in client code.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, I have only one document, But it will be better if it results per document.

Comment: For you to understand the issue here, the only way to do that sort of manipulation is with mapReduce, but all you would be doing is exactly the same sort of manipulation you would do in client code but just running it on the server and not actually "reducing anything". Also the output from mapReduce is very set in form, and therefore will not be an exact output in the form you suggest anyway. Do you know how to iterate a cursor or stream? That would generally be the best aproach to manipulating each document as read.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, I am not going to use this with any serverside code. This will run only on db level to verify whether there are duplicate values in master key or not.

Comment: Like I already said "mapReduce", but it still has to cycle every document even if it only emits when a "duplicate count" is found. The document design is not great as well, as you should not have arbitrary named keys in a database, which is also part of the problem where the only way to do this is with mapReduce. It's per document, so all you are doing is reordering the values to unique keys and adding items to an array for each one. If the count of any array is greater than one then return. Seems a trivial problem, but if it stilll evades you then ask away.